# Gradient ALONG a CGPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgpath

I am drawing an arc that is an almost complete circle:

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, radius, (float)(3.0f * M_PI_2), radians, !clockwise);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGPathRelease(path);
```

I have an arc like path that is an almost complete circle. In this code it is all one color, however, I want one end to be a solid white color and the other to be a `[UIColor clearColor]` so that it **smoothly fades out**.

Every example of code I have found uses a linear gradient. This will not work. **I don't want a linear gradient, but a gradient that travels along the path so that one end is colorA and the other colorB.**

It seems like this should be possible. Is it possible with CoreGraphics? Or if not, another method?

Comment: Any of [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+circular+gradient) help?

Comment: unfortunately, no. i keep looking through searches, but the only results are either for linear (perfectly straight gradient) or radial/circular which is a gradient from a single point outward. No gradients that follow a path